# Suppress properties with null value on ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've created an ASP.Net WEB API Project that will be used by a mobile application. I need the response json to omit null properties instead of return them as `property: null`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

In the `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = 
                 new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore};
```

Or, if you want more control, you can replace entire formatter:

```
var jsonformatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    SerializerSettings =
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    }
};

config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonformatter);
```

Comment: Shame config.Formatters.XmlFormatter doesn't have the same Property... :/

Comment: Since Json.NET 5 (not sure for previous versions), you can also do this: `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` - this will update the null value handling without resetting any other json serialization settings (like using lower case on the first letter of properties)

Comment: Is it possible to get it to do it for just a single property?

Comment: the NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore did not work for my results

Comment: can we implement it in actionfilterattribute

Comment: How can we implement this as a filter for class or method level? @AwaisMahmood

Comment: @Chenna create an attribute and call it on a class level or method level wherever you want

Comment: If the change should happen on a per-property basis, and one is using a sufficiently new version of Json.Net, one can use this attribute on the property: `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]`.

Comment: Still Working :) Thanks

Answer (score 33):

I ended up with this piece of code in the startup.cs file using ASP.NET5 1.0.0-beta7

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Answer (score 22):

For ASP.NET Core 3.0, the `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs` code should contain:

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
    });
```

Comment: This is the best option, because on the API (without MVC) you don't have MVC implemented.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]` attributes

Comment: This is the only answer that covers both the xml and json response.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using vnext, in vnext web api projects, add this code to startup.cs file.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            int position = options.OutputFormatters.FindIndex(f =>  f.Instance is JsonOutputFormatter);

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
            };

            var formatter = new JsonOutputFormatter();
            formatter.SerializerSettings = settings;

            options.OutputFormatters.Insert(position, formatter);
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I cannot comment due to my low reputation. Adding to Dave Wegner's answer since it is obsolete the current solution is:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{  
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).