# Is it possible to ignore null values in a rest response?

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a rest service that returns a json. Everything is working and i was wondering if i could ignore null values in respose because i don't want to send something like:

```
{
"name": "George",
"country": null,
"city": null
}
```

I would like to return something like:

```
{
"name": "George"
}
```

The object that represents a Client is like that:

```
namespace Tests.Domain
{

public class Client
{
    public Client() { }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public City City { get; set; }

}
}
```

And my response is:

```
...
return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)200, clientSession);
```

Thanks in advance.

David L.

Comment: i'm not using JSonNet to serialize..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress properties with null value on ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486667/suppress-properties-with-null-value-on-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **WebApiConfig.Register** method, add the following code after route registration code:

```
   var jsonConfig = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
   jsonConfig.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```