# How to get WebAPI to return JSON for SQL query with varying select clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My application features a query builder which allows users to create a SQL query with a varying select clause.  I need the results to be returned in JSON by WebAPI.
There are a huge number of fields that could feature in the select.
The only approach I have found is to use:

```
var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<SomeObjectWhichDefinesAllPossibleFields>(sql);
return Ok(results);
```

Which relies on me maintaining a SomeObjectWhichDefinesAllPossibleFields class which does as it name suggests.  I would like a more dynamic solution as more fields may be added in the future.

Is there another way to get WebAPI to serialize a SqlQuery with a varying select clause

Comment: Try OData and/or Breeze.

Comment: I am in the same situation. Following this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used TypeBuilder to construct a dynamic Type to pass to the SqlQuery method as per this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206416/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-SqlQuery

This dynamic type was serialized to JSON nicely by web-api.

The only limitation is that it is necessary to know the dynamic field types (whether string, int etc) however in my application that was possible.

Comment: This solution seems overly engineered for such a simple task such as querying the database.

Answer (score 2):

Web Api Repository, can use this:

```
public IList<Models.SalesTargetDetail> getSalesTarget(int SpId){
    System.Text.StringBuilder sbSql = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sbSql.Append(@"select Cast(STD.Qty as varchar(10)) as Qty from tblSalesTarget ST inner join tblSalesTargetDetail STD on ST.Id=STD.SalesTargetId where 1=1");
    sbSql.Append(" and STD.SalesTargetId=" + SpId);
    var data = this.UnitOfWork.Context.Database.SqlQuery<Models.SalesTargetDetail>(sbSql.ToString()).ToList<Models.SalesTargetDetail>();
    return data.ToList<Models.SalesTargetDetail>();
}
```

And the Model is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace NNG.NCPML.Api.Models{
    //[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class SalesTargetDetail{
        public int SalesTargetDetailId{get; set;}
        public string SalesTargetId{get; set;}
        public int ItemInfoId{get; set;}
        public string ItemName{get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code as code by pasting it into the answer and pressing CTRL+K or the `{}` button. Avoid screenshots of code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In WebAPI you can [suppress fields that are null from being serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486667/suppress-properties-with-null-value-on-asp-net-web-api). So you could start out with the dreaded `SomeObjectWhichDefinesAllPossibleFields` class, initialize all properties to null, and only set the properties that are requested in the select clause. You still have to maintain the large class, but if you only select/request two fields, only two fields will be serialized and returned in the JSON result.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ExpandoObject, cast as an IDictionary, and dynamically add properties depending on the fields requested. Here is an example:

Example API Url: http://localhost/api/select/id,title,firstName,lastName

*(add `using System.Dynamic;`)*

```
[Route("api/select/{fieldList}")]
[HttpGet]
public object Dynamic(string fieldList)
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    var dictionary = expando as IDictionary<string, Object>;

    string[] fields = fieldList.Split(',');
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        dictionary.Add(field, "code to get the field value goes here");
    }
    return expando;
}
```

Comment: Not clear to me how to retrieve the query results with this method