# Ignore null and default value from serializer in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to Ignore those property from Json serializing which is null. 
for this I added this line in my `webapi.config` file.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore};

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {          
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{identifier}",
                defaults: new { identifier = RouteParameter.Optional }  
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling= DefaultValueHandling.Ignore };
        }
```

But It is not ignoring those property which is null.

This is my class

```
public class UserProfile
    {
        [JsonProperty("fullname")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("imageid")]
        public int ImageId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dob")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
    }
```

It is Json return from web api

```
    {
  "fullname": "Amit Kumar",
  "imageid": 0,
  "dob": null
}
```

I have not assigned the value of dob and imageid.

I follow this [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486667/suppress-properties-with-null-value-on-asp-net-web-api) , but It didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Do you want to ignore EVERY null property in ANY object you serialize or do you need to selectively decide which property with a null value to ignore?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma: I want to ignore it in every object, that's why I added it globally.

Comment: @MostafizurRahman: No. That is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at [Newtonsoft.Json source code](https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonPropertyAttribute.cs) I believe that the `JsonPropertyAttribute` decorating your class properties is overriding the default `NullValueHandling` specified in `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Either remove such attribute (if you want to use the globally defined NullValueHandling) or specify `NullValueHandling` explicitly:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [JsonProperty("fullname")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("imageid")]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dob", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I removed those JsonProperty, But still the problem is same.

Comment: It's truly a strange behavior. I tried to reproduce the issue in a new web API project, but everything is working fine. With current information I do not have any clue about what could be wrong. Try adding the content of your Startup.cs or Global.asax.cs file to the question.