# RESTful web service in c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm building a RESTful web service in c#.

So I have build this DTo Model like this:

```
namespace WebService.Models
{
    [DataContract(Name = "VitalSigns")]
    public class VitalSignsDTO
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id", Order = 1)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name", Order = 2)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "valore", Order = 3)]
        public string valore { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "dataOra", Order = 3)]
        public DateTime? dataOra { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, this is the response of JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Altezza corporea",
    "valore": null,
    "dataOra": null
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Peso corporeo",
    "valore": null,
    "dataOra": null
}
```

now I want to know, if is possible to hidden valore and dataOra field that not have a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore a property in class if null, using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net)

Comment: If you are returning an array/collection of json objects I don't think you want to omit fields because it will make it more difficult for the consumer to deal with some that are there and some that are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to your property.

```
namespace WebService.Models
{
    [DataContract(Name = "VitalSigns")]
    public class VitalSignsDTO
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id", Order = 1)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name", Order = 2)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        [DataMember(Name = "valore", Order = 3)]
        public string valore { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        [DataMember(Name = "dataOra", Order = 3)]
        public DateTime? dataOra { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `dataOra` is set, will it be included in the JSON?

Comment: No, it will not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in **.Net Core WebAPI**, you can configure JSON Serializer in the middleware (Startup.cs).

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore; });
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.RegisterServices();
    }
```

If you are in **ASP.NET WebAPI**, refer [Suppress properties with null value on ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486667/suppress-properties-with-null-value-on-asp-net-web-api)